# Why does dropna() not work?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-quickstart-vm

System: Spark 1.3.0 (Anaconda Python dist.) on Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.4

Here's a Spark DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data = sc.parallelize([('Foo',41,'US',3),
                       ('Foo',39,'UK',1),
                       ('Bar',57,'CA',2),
                       ('Bar',72,'CA',3),
                       ('Baz',22,'US',6),
                       (None,75,None,7)])

schema = StructType([StructField('Name', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Age', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('Country', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Score', IntegerType(), True)])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data,schema)
```

`data.show()`

```
Name Age Country Score
Foo  41  US      3    
Foo  39  UK      1    
Bar  57  CA      2    
Bar  72  CA      3    
Baz  22  US      6    
null 75  null    7
```

However neither of these work!

```
df.dropna()
df.na.drop()
```

I get this message:

```
>>> df.show()
Name Age Country Score
Foo  41  US      3    
Foo  39  UK      1    
Bar  57  CA      2    
Bar  72  CA      3    
Baz  22  US      6    
null 75  null    7    
>>> df.dropna().show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 580, in __getattr__
    jc = self._jdf.apply(name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o50.apply.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "dropna" among (Name, Age, Country, Score);
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:162)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.resolve(DataFrame.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.col(DataFrame.scala:436)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.apply(DataFrame.scala:426)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Has anybody else experienced this problem? What's the workaround? Pyspark seems to thing that I am looking for a column called "na". Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**tl;dr** The methods `na` and `dropna` are only available since Spark 1.3.1.

Few mistakes you made:

1. `data = sc.parallelize([....('',75,'', 7 )])`, you intended to use `''` to represent `None`, however, it's just a String instead of null
2. `na` and `dropna` are both methods on dataFrame class, therefore, you should call it with your `df`.

Runnable Code:

```py
data = sc.parallelize([('Foo',41,'US',3),
                       ('Foo',39,'UK',1),
                       ('Bar',57,'CA',2),
                       ('Bar',72,'CA',3),
                       ('Baz',22,'US',6),
                       (None, 75, None, 7)])

schema = StructType([StructField('Name', StringType(), True),
                 StructField('Age', IntegerType(), True),
                 StructField('Country', StringType(), True),
                 StructField('Score', IntegerType(), True)])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data,schema)

df.dropna().show()
df.na.drop().show()
```

Answer (score -1):

I realize that the question was asked a yr ago, in-case leaving the solution for Scala, below in-case someone lands here looking for the same

```
val data = sc.parallelize(List(("Foo",41,"US",3), ("Foo",39,"UK",1),   
("Bar",57,"CA",2), ("Bar",72,"CA",3), ("Baz",22,"US",6), (None, 75,  
   None, 7)))
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("Name", StringType, true),   
  StructField("Age", IntegerType, true), StructField("Country", 
  StringType, true), StructField("Score", IntegerType, true)))

val dat = data.map(d => Row(d._1, d._2, d._3, d._4))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dat, schema)
df.na.drop()
```

Note:
The above solution will still fail to give the right result in Scala, not sure what is different in the implementation between Scala and python binding. *na.drop* works if the missing data is represented as *null*. It fails for "" and None. One alternative around the same is to make use of *withColumn* function to handle missing values of different forms