# PySpark dataframe: filter records with four or more non-null columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a number of PySpark dataframes where the data in two of the columns are mandatory, and the other columns are optional. The mandatory columns contain a date and a record ID; the most valuable data resides in the optional columns. I'm trying to capture the connections between elements in the optional columns.

The dataframe, pre-filter:

```
id     col1    col2    col3    date
123            xyz             20160401
234    abc     pqr             20160401
345    def     hij     klm     20160401
456                            20160401
```

Post-filter, the dataframe would look like this:

```
id     col1    col2    col3    date
234    abc     pqr             20160401
345    def     hij     klm     20160401
```

The records with multiple non-null column values are interesting because they describe relationships.

I notice that PySpark has a `.filter` method. The examples in the documentation typically show filtering a column, e.g. `df_filtered = df.filter(df.some_col > some_value)`. I'm trying to write a filter to capture all those records with four or more non-null columns for an *arbitrary* dataframe, i.e. the column names must not be explicitly stated.

Is there an easy way to do this in PySpark?

#### Update

Although `.dropna(thresh=4)` seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, for some reason it didn't work. E.g.

```
df.collect()

[Row(id=123, col1=None,         col2=None, col3=3754907743, date='20160403'),
 Row(id=124, col1=7911019393,   col2=None, col3=1456473867, date='20160403'),
 Row(id=125, col1=None,         col2=None, col3=2049622472, date='20160403'),
 Row(id=126, col1=4345043212,   col2=None, col3=3168577324, date='20160403'),
 Row(id=127, col1=None,         col2=None, col3=3185277065, date='20160403'),
 Row(id=128, col1=1336048242,   col2=None, col3=1322345860, date='20160403')]
```

Regardless of the `thresh` number, it always returns all the records in the original dataframe:

```
df_filtered = df.dropna(thresh=[any number])

df_filtered.collect()

[Row(id=123, col1=None,         col2=None, col3=3754907743, date='20160403'),
 Row(id=124, col1=7911019393,   col2=None, col3=1456473867, date='20160403'),
 Row(id=125, col1=None,         col2=None, col3=2049622472, date='20160403'),
 Row(id=126, col1=4345043212,   col2=None, col3=3168577324, date='20160403'),
 Row(id=127, col1=None,         col2=None, col3=3185277065, date='20160403'),
 Row(id=128, col1=1336048242,   col2=None, col3=1322345860, date='20160403')]
```

I'm running Spark version 1.5.0-cdh5.5.2.

Comment: [`dropna`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna) won't work?

Comment: [This might help you figure out why dropna isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253550/why-does-dropna-not-work)...

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna), you're looking for `dropna`:

> *dropna(how='any', thresh=None, subset=None)*
>
> Returns a new DataFrame omitting rows with null values.
>   DataFrame.dropna() and DataFrameNaFunctions.drop() are aliases of each
>   other.-
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> how – ‘any’ or ‘all’. If ‘any’, drop a row if it contains any nulls.
>        If ‘all’, drop a row only if all its values are null.
>
> thresh – int, default None If specified, drop rows that have less than
>          thresh non-null values. This overwrites the how parameter.
>
> subset – optional list of column names to consider.
> ```

So, to answer your question, you could try `df.dropna(thresh=4)`.

Comment: Thanks @AkshatMahajan. `dropna(thresh=...)` seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. For some strange reason, it didn't work.

Comment: @AlexWoolford I've been trying to replicate what you're going through, and I concur - `dropna` does work a bit unexpectedly. I've found though that it does work for unintuitive values of `thresh` - what test numbers did you try for it?

Comment: It appears `thresh` indicates at least how many columns must be non-null. If I have three rows, of which exactly one has two non-null columns, then the only  way to get rid of it is to set `thresh`=3.

Comment: I tried 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. They all returned the original dataframe.

Comment: @AlexWoolford: So I tried to recreate your actual dataframe using the snapshot you posted above from `collect()`, and keep being told that 'some types cannot be determined after inferring' when trying to convert a list of Rows to dataframe. Could the issue be simply that the types are not well-defined in your dataframe?

Comment: I mention this because I can reproduce how `dropna` should work with a simpler dataset: d = [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1,'he':23}, {'name':'Abs','age':2,'he':None}, {'name':None, 'age': None, 'he': 2},{k: None for k in ['name','age','he']}].

Comment: That's an interesting thought, @AkshatMahajan. I ran `df.dtypes` and see that the columns are `string` and `bigint` types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108121/discussion-between-akshat-mahajan-and-alex-woolford).